# How to inspect two tables at the same time in wagtail modeladmin?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

In my question, there are two related models:

```
class Simulation(index.Indexed, ClusterableModel):
    name = models.CharField("算例名称", max_length=255, blank=True)    name = models.CharField("算例名称", max_length=255, blank=True)
    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('name', classname="col10"),
            MultiFieldPanel([InlinePanel('simulation',label='simulation_software'),]),
        ], "算例")
    ]
class SimulationSoftware(index.Indexed, ClusterableModel):
    simulation = ParentalKey(Simulation, related_name='simulation', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    software = models.ForeignKey(DicSoftware, verbose_name="模拟软件", help_text="/admin/home/dicsoftware/", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='+')
    scale = models.IntegerField("规模", blank=True);
    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
                FieldPanel('simulation', classname="col12"),
                FieldPanel('software', classname="col12"),
                FieldPanel('scale', classname="col12"),
        ], "算例输入")
    ]
```

I use modeladmin to manage the data in these two tables. When I inspect one Simulation instance, I can not inspect the SimulationSoftware related to it.

How can I inspect two table data at the same time?

Wish for your help.

Comment: Any codes for `InspectView`?

Comment: I have not rewrite InspectView. Is there any way to use the functionability wagtail already have to implement this?

Comment: Take a look at [inspect.html](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/192a74835a716ba3967f0fd2768535bf78f99766/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/templates/modeladmin/inspect.html) if that's what you mean "inspect". You have to provide custom template to view a foreign key. If you mean the edit page, see `edit.html`. Provide more code and maybe some captures may help people understand your question better.